# Array decays to pointer as function parameter

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion

I know following function definitions are considered the same by c compiler

```
void test(int* array);   // all converted to first one
void test(int array[]);
void test(int array[3]);
```

and in C99 standard

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and **is not an lvalue**. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

my questions is after `int array[]` decays to a pointer, then it's also a lvalue as local variable in function call, does it violate the standard that converted pointer should not be a lvalue?

Comment: The quote is about expressions, not declarations. There's no "decay" in parameter declarations, they're all just equivalent to pointer declarations.

Comment: Hi @Barmar good catch, do you by any chance know where in the standard I can find the declaration conversion rule? Thx

Comment: See C99 6.7.5.3 paragraph 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem as there's two things in play here: the adjustment of array parameters to pointers, and how function parameters are set.

The equivalency of the three declarations you gave is spelled out in section 6.7.6.3p7 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
> ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
> those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation. If
> the keyword static also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type
> derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
> corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
> element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
> size expression

So this means that in all of the above cases, the type of the parameter `array` is `int *`.

Then there's how parameters are populated.  This is specified in 6.5.2.2p4 regarding function calls:

> An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In
> preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and
> each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument

So given the following:

```
int a[5];
test(a);
```

Internally, there's an assignment, i.e. `array = a` from the passed parameter value to the function's actual parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> my questions is after int array[] decays to a pointer, then it's also
> a lvalue as local variable in function call, does it violate the
> standard that converted pointer should not be a lvalue?

The quote means that after the implicit conversion of an array to a pointer to its first element the pointer is not an lavlue. For example, the compiler will issue an error if you will write for example

```
int a[10];
++a;
```

In this expression `++a` the array designator `a` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element but the pointer is not an lvalue. You may not increment it. If you would write intead

```
int a[10];
int *p = a;
++p;
```

then the expression `++p` is correct because `p` is an lvalue.

As for a function like that

```
void test(int array[]);
```

then a passed array is converted to a pointer to its first element and the pointer is not an lvalue. But the pointer is used to initialize the parameter of the function that is adjusted by the compiler to the type int *. And of course the parameter is an lvalue within the function.

Similarly, if you have a function that returns an array that is converted to a pointer to its first element like for example

```
int * test( void )
{
    static int a[10];

    return a;
}
```

then again the returned pointer is not lvalue.  For example you may not write

```
printf( "%p\n", ( void * )++test() );
```

That is you may not increment the returned pointer.